# Removing quotes from console log in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

I'm trying to remove the printed single quotations which occur while running the following code.

I've tried playing around with the replace(`/['"]+/g, ''`but I'm not getting this correctly.

```
var arr = ["Alpha", "Omega", "Delta"];
var symbol = "weee";
for(x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
    console.log(x,symbol,arr[x]);
}
```

This returns:

```
0 'weee' 'Alpha'

1 'weee' 'Omega'

2 'weee' 'Delta'
```

Comment: don't use chrome, it's the only console that does that (well, not quite ... my console uses double quotes in the output) ... anyway ... who cares how strings a shown in a debugging tool - it makes no difference to the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the types of `console.log` parameters are different, string type will be marked by quotation marks, so you can make the parameters to a single string, just like:

```
 console.log(x + ' ' + symbol + ' ' +arr[x]);
```

Comment: In other words, you need to give it only a single string.